# UILabel to control a UItextfield in another view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uilabel

I am using Xcode 4.3 and I have a label in one view controller that I want to update the text in a text field in another view controller. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the text in your model class (assuming that you have one; if you don't, you need to create it). When the end-user edits the text field, your code should change the string in your model; when the label displays, you should read its text from the model. The easiest way of sharing your model among multiple classes is to define a [*singleton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Header:

```
@interface Model : NSObject
@property (NSString*) labelText;
+(Model*)instance;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation Model
@synthesize labelText;
+(Model*)instance{
    static Model *inst;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        inst = [[Model alloc] init];
    });
    return inst;
}
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        labelText = @"Initial Text";
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Using the model:

```
// Setting the field in the model, presumably in textFieldDidEndEditing:
// of your UITextField delegate
[Model instance].labelText = textField.text;

// Getting the field from the model, presumably in viewWillAppear
myLabel.text = [Model instance].labelText;
```

Comment: is the model class a subclass of the first view controller?

Comment: @user1497323 No, a model class is a holder of the state of your application, as in [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1). Take a look at the edit for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example, are you maybe using a different version of Xcode? I am having an error saying it doesn't recognize the type "Model". Do you know another way to declare or call the model?

Comment: @user1497323 `Model` is an example of a class that you should define for your app. Add `Model.h` and `Model.m`, put the code in them, and add `#import "Model.h"` to your view controllers. You can now set `[Model instance].labelText` when the field is edited, and when the label needs to be set.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you give me an example of how the code for setting the field and label would go?

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works great but only when you click in the target text field does it display the new value as defined in the other view controller. Is there anything I can do to make it update immediatedly?

Comment: @user1497323 Add `-(id)init` method to the `Model.m`, and set the value of `labelText` to the initial text that you would like to be there. Currently it is initialized to `nil`, so you do not see anything. I edited the answer to add an example of how you can do it.

Comment: Hmm the target text field still only displays the initial value once the the user clicks in the text field. Is there any way to make the value display right away without the necessity of clicking in the field?

Comment: @user1497323 You should copy the content of `[Model instance].labelText` into your text field in the `viewWillAppear` of the controller for the view containing the text field.

Comment: Copy [Model instance].labelText into the text field in the viewWillAppear? Not quite sure how that would go.. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user1497323 Go to the view controller of the view with your text field, find its `viewWillAppear` method, and add `myTextfield.text = [Model instance].labelText;` to that method.